# Forwarding Ports on MSA development on local environment(MAC)

Tags: networking, portforwarding

I want to make an development environment like this.

```
http://local-a.com -> redirects to localhost:8080
https://local-a.com -> redirects to localhost:8443

http://local-b.com -> redirects to localhost:8090
https://local-b.com -> redirects to localhost:9443

http://local-c.com -> redirecnts to localhost:8100
https://local-c.com -> redirects to localhost:10443
```

Can you suggest how to do that?
It seems /etc/pf.conf file and /etc/hosts files can do this but I am very confused about how to do this.

Just a few guides of links would be helpful for me.
Thank you.

- reference: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332145/mapping-port-80-to-8080-but-maintain-explicit-8080-access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I clear my question by this method.
/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 local-a.com
127.0.0.1 local-b.com
127.0.0.1 local-c.com
```

using nginx.conf

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name local-a.com;
  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Front-Server-Ip $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto 'http';
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
  }
}
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name local-b.com;
  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Front-Server-Ip $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto 'http';
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8090;
  }
}
...
```